# Insight.Database column mapping to object

Tags: c#, sql, orm, insight.database

I'm using [`Insight.Database`](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) as our *micro-ORM*. I wanted to figure out if there is a way to take the following POCO class associations and map results from a single row into these objects.

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RuleDetail Source { get; set; }
    public RuleDetail Destination { get; set; }
}

public class RuleDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Name { get; set; }
    public Date DateTime { get; set; }
    // omitted...
}
```

Here is the columns that are returned from our stored procedure:

```
Id
Name

// Should map to Source object.
SourceId
SourceName
SourceDateTime

// Should map to Destination object.
DestinationId
DestinationName
DestinationDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a little bit of setup on the query side. Not sure if it is possible with attributes.

```
var returns = Query.Returns(
    new OneToOne<Rule, RuleDetail, RuleDetail>(
        callback: (rule, source, destination) => {
            rule.Source = source;
            rule.Destination = destination;
        },
        columnOverride: new ColumnOverride[] {
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("SourceId", "Id"),
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("SourceName", "Name"),
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("SourceDateTime", "DateTime"),
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("DestinationId", "Id"),
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("DestinationName", "Name"),
            new ColumnOverride<RuleDetail>("DestinationDateTime", "DateTime"),
        },
        splitColumns: new Dictionary<Type, string>() {
            { typeof(Rule), "Id" },
            { typeof(RuleDetail), "SourceId" },
            { typeof(RuleDetail), "DestinationId" },
        }
    )
);
return Db.Query(procedure, params, returns);
```

I'm not sure if all of that code is required to make it work, but it definitely shows how powerful the querying in Insight.Database can be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
public interface IRepo
{
    [Recordset(1, typeof(RuleDetail), into="Source", IsChild=true)]
    [Recordset(2, typeof(RuleDetail), into="Destination", IsChild=true)] 
    Rule GetFullyPopulatedRuleByIdStoredProcedure(int id);
}
```

You'll need to return three recordsets - the first [Recordset(0)] being your Rule, the other two containing Source and Destination.  I use this arrangement a lot, it works nicely for me.

I don't know of any way to do this if you're returning a single row in a single recordset.